# shell_exec shows multiple line output as single line

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

I am trying to execute java file using `shell_exec()` command, but the output formatting is not as per the expectation. Here are the details

**code:**

```
 echo shell_exec("java WekaExample");
```

**output:**

```
 Accuracy of J48: 50.00% --------------------------------- Accuracy of PART: 50.00% --------------------------------- Accuracy of DecisionTable: 64.29% --------------------------------- Accuracy of DecisionStump: 21.43% ---------------------------------
```

**Expected Output:**(As displayed when running the command in terminal)

```
  Accuracy of J48: 50.00%
  ---------------------------------
  Accuracy of PART: 50.00%
  ---------------------------------
  Accuracy of DecisionTable: 64.29%
  ---------------------------------
  Accuracy of DecisionStump: 21.43%
  ---------------------------------
```

Any type of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Where are you outputting that result? Windows or Linux/Unix/Mac?

Comment: @apokryfos on the web page [Win/Linux doesn't matter]

Comment: @geeksal If that's the case, look in view source and see if that shows up correctly. Browsers generally expect HTML, so \n \r aren't going to be rendered.

Comment: @JonStirling you are correct \n is not rendered. So how could I render the output is such a way that \n is outputted as <br>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to convert the newlines (which probably really is there in the raw output) to `<br />` tags for your browser to render them on separate lines. Use `nl2br()`, like:

```
echo nl2br(shell_exec("java WekaExample"));
```

Or put `<pre></pre>` tags around your output instead so the newlines are actually printed as new lines.